# Passing data to a new page and writing it

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to pass data from text boxes using **GetElementById**.

this is my text box:

```
<tr>
<td>Your name:</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="name" id = "p_name"/><br /></td>

</tr>
```

And these are my functions:

```
function mypopup()
{
     mywindow = window.open("Page_preview.html","width=200,height=200");
     mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);

}
function load()
{
    document.write("<p>" + Date() + "</p>");

    var myTextField = document.getElementById('p_name');
     if(myTextField.value != "")
     alert("You entered: " + myTextField.value)
}
```

The load method is called inside the **page_preview.html** body.

This is the button which starts mypopup function:

```
<input type="button" onclick="mypopup()" value="Show preview" />
```

Every thing works except the **document.getElementById('p_name')** never returns a value, like it can't find it.

I am sure it can be done easily ( i am new to this ).

Comment: `document.getElementById()` will get an element _in the current document,_ that is, it doesn't look in other windows. One way to pass the data from one window to the next is to use `.getElementById()` in your `mypopup()` function and pass the value to "Page_preview.html" in the query string, i.e., when you open the second window set the url to `"Page_preview.html?name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("p_name").value)`

Answer (score 1):

If your form has a `name`, and the text field has a `name`, you can use `document.myForm.myTextbox.value`.

```
<form name='myForm'>
    <input type='text' name='myTextbox'>
```

Also, make sure your page has actually fully loaded before you perform actions on the DOM - if your `page_preview.html` runs the javascript BEFORE the text field loads, that will cause it to always be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add value on your onclick event? I mean pass parameters to your function. something like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="mypopup(document.getElementById('p_name').value)" value="Show preview" />
```

In your javascript function, it would be like this

```
function load(p_name)
{
  document.write("<p>" + Date() + "</p>");

  var myTextField = p_name;
  if(myTextField.value != "")
  alert("You entered: " + myTextField.value)
}
```

Or maybe the error is in your getElementById. Please add .value on this part:

```
 var myTextField = document.getElementById('p_name');
```

Make it like this:

```
 var myTextField = document.getElementById('p_name').value;
```

I think that would fix it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery

```
$('#p_name').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` overwrites the html in your page, so after that line executes `<input type="text" name="name" id = "p_name"/>` no longer exists. Try modifying the contents of a `div` (or `span` or `p`, etc.) for output instead.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Example JS:

```
var outputElement = document.getElementById;
var msgs = 'This is a better way to monitor output';
var htmlMsgs = '<p>This is a better way to monitor output</p>';
outputElement.innerText = msgs;
//outputElement.innerHTML = htmlMsgs; //for formatted output.
```